# Kha with descender (the "ҳ" symbol)

Tags: characters, cyrillic

So, using pdfLaTeX, I need to write the [Kha with descender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kha_with_descender) symbol (which looks like ҳ). Taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:CYRILLIC_LETTER_HA_WITH_DESCENDER.PNG):

[image]

It comes up with Afghan history, if anyone's curious why I need it...

I know this can be done with XeLaTeX, but I'd prefer **avoiding XeLaTeX** if possible (I'm also using microtype).

Using Babel for one character seems excessive...what other options are there?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These characters are available in font encoding T2A, for example. They can
be used without babel:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
  U+04B2: {\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont\CYRHDSC}

  U+04B3: {\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont\cyrhdsc}
\end{document}
```

In order to avoid PK-Fonts the package cm-super should be installed.

Answer (score 9):

Adding to Heiko's excellent answer, one can also input the character directly, provided the file is UTF8 encoded:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{Ҳ}{{\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont\CYRHDSC}}
\newunicodechar{ҳ}{{\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont\cyrhdsc}}

\begin{document}
  U+04B2: {\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont\CYRHDSC} Ҳ

  U+04B3: {\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont\cyrhdsc} ҳ
\end{document}
```

Of course Russian (or other language using the character) `babel` should not be used.

Comment: This was a fantastic answer, I really appreciate your solution :)