# How can I input Cyrillic extended letters with \newunicodechar?

Tags: luatex, cyrillic, extended-characters

I'm trying to write Tatar (a language with some Cyrillic extensions әөүһңҗ) with `\newunicodechar` in LuaLaTeX like this (example with Ә):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage[X2, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newunicodechar{Ә}{{\fontencoding{X2}\selectfont\CYRSCHWA}}

\begin{document}
Ә
\end{document}
```

Then I get the following error message:
`The first argument to \newunicodechar is either too long or an invalid sequence of bytes` at the line `\newunicodechar{Ә}{{\fontencoding{X2}\selectfont\CYRSCHWA}}`.

I tried the same thing with the first argument being other random characters like `†` or `海`, and then it works and the typeset shows a correct result.
So I'm guessing that the problem lies in the character in the first argument `Ә`, but so far I cannot figure out anymore.
Do you have any ideas?

I also checked [a case in an Azeri letter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361581/how-can-i-use-azerbaijani-characterhttps://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361581/how-can-i-use-azerbaijani-characters), [Church Slavonic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506443/little-yus-cyrillic-in-latex), and [kha with descender (ҳ)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64943/kha-with-descender-the-%D2%B3-symbol).

Comment: you shouldn't use inputenc and fontenc like this with lualatex. They are for pdflatex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for your quick answer! Apparently I misread the [documentation](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/newunicodechar/newunicodechar.pdf) of `newunicodechar`, and it required neither `fontenc` nor `inputenc` for LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Comment: FYI, I tried to use `newunicodechar` to embed Tatar characters (extended Cyrillic) in a text written in English (not a Tatar monoligual document).

Answer (score 4):

As Ulrike commented, you should use neither `inputenc` nor `fontenc` in LuaLaTeX. Instead you can include Cyrillic letters in your documents by just selecting a font which includes these characters. If you like LuaLaTeX's default font "Latin Modern Roman", you might want to use "New Computer Modern", a Latin Modern variant which includes Cyrillic letters:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}

\begin{document}
әөүһңҗ
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Marcel, thank you for your quick answer and MWE!
I just ran it on LuaLaTeX, but I got a similar error:
`Undefined control sequence.`
`l.5 \UTF{04D9}\UTF{04E9}\UTF{04AF}\UTF{04BB}\UTF{04A3}\UTF{0497}`

Does this have to do with encoding?

Comment: Did you run Marcel's exact example or did you add something?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I ran the exact example given by Marcel.

Comment: Then show the complete log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The log file looks a little lengthy, so I uploaded it on [Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yCzuJY43vgkx8S597Ek5-6b98wrhN1Ao/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: @Chihiro That log file looks incomplete, but the part does not show any error.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I doubted my TeXLive setting or version (I'm using TeXLive2020), so I'm upgrading it to 2021 now. Meanwhile I tried the same code with Overleaf, and it correctly showed the output! For now I'll do with Overleaf, and will also try on local later. Thank you very much for your helps!!

Comment: Also big thanks to @MarcelKrüger!